# How to add a Silverlight page into a SharePoint 2010 Application Page?

Tags: silverlight

How to add a Silverlight page into a SharePoint 2010 Application Page? I know how to deploy the .xap file by adding the SL project as a module in a SharePoint 2010 project and create the .wsp file using VS2010. But you still have to use a SP2010 content page to add the Silverlight webpart to consume it. How to add it to the Application Page.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx) on how to add an application page to a Visual Studio 2010 / SharePoint project.

This is only available for farm solution projects, not for Sandboxed projects so make sure you are not using Sandboxed. For full list of differences between these two [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361616.aspx).

Comment: If you need to do it in the Sandbox. Then use this approach to create a page http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Custom-application-pages-in-the-SharePoint-2010-Sandbox.aspx and just use the Silverlight Web Part and the XAP file in a doc lib (or similar)

Comment: +1 WOW this is awesome

Comment: The question is NOT how to create a application page. Rather how to add your silverlight code in an application page and being able to debug in a farm based VS project (not a sandbox). I am aware of the approach linked by Toni as well and that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @wictor - do you think we can just use the object tag generated by the silverlight webpart? But I still won't be able to debug it along with the rest of the SharePoint projects.

Comment: Ok, if you want to debug Silverlight code in your SharePoint solution then you need to go into the project properties and select Enable Silverlight Debugging on the SharePoint settings tab.

Comment: And it works only when you are developing a web part and not an application page right?